# How to make a column that shows rows with a certain keyword?

Tags: python

Need to make a new column called `keyword` where from the `review_mo` column certain keywords appear. The keywords I am interested in extracting are "love","big","small", "bikini" and "happy".

`keywords= "love","big","small", "bikini","happy"`

The code I have inputted works for what I am trying to do but for my next project there are going to be 500 keywords and this won't be a practical approach any longer. Want to know if somebody can help pass a sort of string list into the function that will take care of this

How to make a column that shows rows with a certain keyword.

```
def is_keyword(value):
    strings = value.split()
    if str('love') in str(strings):
        return 1
    if str('big') in str(strings):
        return 1
    if str('small') in str(strings):
        return 1
    if str('bikini') in str(strings):
        return 1
    if str('happy') in str(strings):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

shopbop['keyword'] = shopbop['review_mo'].apply(is_keyword)
```

What I want to do is replace all the "if" lines with just a single line instead of 5 lines and somehow just input the "keywords" string list instead

Comment: row and column in what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `any` to return `True` on the first match or `False` if no match

```
if any(word in strings for word in keywords):
    return 1
else:
    return 0
```

---

`keywords` should be a list object

```
keywords= ["love","big","small", "bikini","happy"]
```

Comment: I get this error when I input this code: NameError: name 'strings' is not defined

Comment: def keyword_solution(value):
    strings = value.split()

if any(word in strings for word in keywords):
    return 1
else:
    return 0
shopbop['keywords'] = shopbop['review_mo'].apply(keyword_solutionword_solution)